# Regex to remove a specific repeated character

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to create a regex in C# that removes a specific character if it is repeated and so it is not the last character of the string.

Example:

```
"a--b-c-" => "a-b-c"
"-a-b--c" => "a-b-c"
"--a--b--c--" => "a-b-c"
```

I never want the - repeated, and I never want it to be the first or last character of my string. How could I write a regex to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Probably easiest to do this in two steps. First replace each occurrence of one or more "-" with a single "-", then trim any leading/trailing "-".

```
var reducedString = Regex.Replace(inputString, "-+", "-");

var finalString = reducedString.Trim('-');
```

Comment: Just FYI, `Trim()` accepts "params", so all you need is `.Trim('-')`

Comment: Is the selection class even necessary? ([]'s)

Comment: Probably not, but I knew that - needed to be escaped when in a character range, while I didn't know if it had special meaning outside one.

Comment: this is bad. dont use it

Comment: @jaxxbo - Care to elaborate as to why?

Comment: @KeithS, inputstring used was "flower..plant.json" , replacing ".+" , after using the above, the finalString was empty. it only works for "-" strange.

Comment: The period character has special meaning in a Regex; it matches any single character in the string. To match a period specifically, you have to escape it: `"\.+"`. That wasn't the OP's situation; he wanted to remove dashes which have no special meaning in a Regex pattern.

Answer (score 8):

For this specific problem, I'd probably not use a regex. Instead, I'd probably use a combination of `String.Split` and `String.Join`, which will be simpler and likely faster:

Like this:

```
string.Join("-", s.Split(new char[] {'-'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

With tests:

```
using System;
class Program
{
    static string RemoveDashes(string s)
    {
        return string.Join("-", s.Split(new char[] { '-' }, 
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tuple<string, string>[] tests = new Tuple<string,string> [] 
        {
            new Tuple<string, string> ("a--b-c-", "a-b-c"),
            new Tuple<string, string> ("-a--b-c-", "a-b-c"),
            new Tuple<string, string> ("--a--b--c--", "a-b-c"),
        };
        foreach (var t in tests)
        {
            string s = RemoveDashes(t.Item1);
            Console.WriteLine("{3}: {0} => Expected: {1}, Actual: {2}", 
                        t.Item1, t.Item2, s, s == t.Item2 ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: creative solution, I actually prefer this to the regex

Answer (score 3):

```
string tidyText = Regex.Replace(originalText, "^-+|(?<=-)-+|-+$", "");
```

Comment: does this remove the dashes at the beginning en end?  I don't think so.

Comment: @LukeH & Brad Christie: I see it does remove the dashes at the edges as well I only don't understand why. Could you explain why this is?

Comment: @Stofke - I'm late to the party, but if you're still wondering: The `^-+` and `-+$` clauses will match strings of hyphens at the beginning and end of the string, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for Regex, but the second you have to change, or re-read, that code most people just rewrite it because it's faster than having to relearn what the code's doing. 2 lines using the built in string methods will be so much easier than having to re-read future regex. And it's faster in some cases.

```
        string text = "--a-b--c-";
        text = text.Replace( "--", "-" );
        text = text.Trim( '-' );
```

Comment: This is close, but it will turn `--a-b---c-` into `a-b--c`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier accomplished without regular expressions.  Something like the following (untested):

```
string s = "--a--b--c--";
string t = "";

bool atStart = true;
bool inHyphen = false;

foreach (char c in s) {
    if (c != "-") {
        if (atStart) {
            atStart = false;
        } else if (inHyphen) {
            inHyphen = false;
            t += "-";
        }
        t += c;
    } else {
        inHyphen = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dismissile: I'm a pragmatist. To me solving the problem is way more important than caring how it's actually done.  **EDIT** See @KeithS's or @LukeH's answer for a Regex-based solution.

Comment: I understand your line of thinking...but I like shorter code :)