# RegEx to replace more than one hyphen with one hyphen in a string? asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

```
string inputString = "Flat---Head-----Self-Tap-Scr---ews----3-x-10mm-8pc";
string outputString = "Flat-Head-Self-Tap-Scr-ews-3-x-10mm-8pc";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string inputString = "Flat---Head-----Self-Tap-Scr---ews----3-x-10mm-8pc";
string outputString = Regex.Replace(inputString , @"-+", "-", RegexOptions.None);
```

Comment: This question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111967/regex-to-remove-a-specific-repeated-character/5112032#5112032, as is this answer, which is spot-on.

Answer (score 2):

Regex: `-+`, replace with `-`. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

```
text = "Flat---Head-----Self-Tap-Scr---ews----3-x-10mm-8pc";
while (text.Contains("--"))
{
    text = text.Replace("--", "-");
}
```

You can also use `Split` by`-` and  use `Join`

```
text = "Flat---Head-----Self-Tap-Scr---ews----3-x-10mm-8pc";
string result = string.Join("-", text.Split(new[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

The second answer isn't my own answer, I got it from this question
[c# Trim commas until text appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362827/c-sharp-trim-commas-until-text-appears/60363019#60363019). I wanted to add you more variables :)