# c# Trim commas until text appears

Tags: c#, string, split

I try to remove any commas from my strings, but not all of them. I've searched for this all over the forum but I cant find a solution to it. Let me explain it with an example:

So basically, I have a file with many lines. They look like this:

```
,,,,,9,33380,32785,14,,,,,50,,,,,,3,,,,600
,,,,19,33399,32774,14,,,,,50,,,,,,2,,,,600
,,,,19,33399,32784,14,,,,,50,,,,,,3,,,,600
,,,,38,33380,32789,14,,,,,50,,,,,,1,,,,600
,,,,38,33404,32793,14,,,,,50,,,,,,1,,,,600
,,,,79,33394,32795,14,,,,,50,,,,,,2,,,,600
,,,,83,33396,32789,14,,,,,50,,,,,,5,,,,600
,,,100,33399,32779,14,,,,,50,,,,,,3,,,,600
,,,101,33399,32797,14,,,,,50,,,,,,2,,,,600
```

The output I want is to keep a single comma between the values. And also remove any leading commas from beginning of string. Like this:

```
9,33380,32785,14,50,3,600
19,33399,32774,14,50,2,600
19,33399,32784,14,50,3,600
38,33380,32789,14,50,1,600
38,33404,32793,14,50,1,600
79,33394,32795,14,50,2,600
83,33396,32789,14,50,5,600
100,33399,32779,14,50,3,600
101,33399,32797,14,50,2,600
```

I've tried to use `text.Replace(',','')` but then it removes them all.
Unfortunately I am not very good at RegEx either and I don't even know if this is possible with that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following regex to condense multiple commas into one and then `Trim` to remove any leading or trailing commas

```
var result = Regex.Replace(inpyut, ",+", ",").Trim(',');
```

Comment: This looks like the logical approach to take.

Answer (score 3):

There are couple solutions

Splitting by `,` delimiter and removing empty entries (',,'), and then rebuilding the string with the same `,` delimiter.

```
var result = string.Join(",", ",,,,,9,33380,3272774,,".Split(new [] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly! I didn't know about the `.Join` and the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`. Amazing!

Comment: By the way, how could I split them into different strings? So the delimiter would be the comma. When I do this: `var x = result.Split(',')[0];` I get the first numbers. But when I do `var b = result.Split(',')[1];` I get an error saying: `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'` Shouldn't the `[1]` be the second word (after the first comma)?

Comment: Split the string using the comma character, remove any empty entries, and then take the result and put a comma between each item. Sure it works, but it is a **hack** ;)

Comment: Do you have any example of that? I've tried using `.First()` and then I get the first value. But if I do `.Skip(1)` to get the second one, I get the same error. I've tried numerous ways to split it by comma. Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, And if i'll write a function, that will iterate every character, take only comma, that doesn't have a next comma, and then push it into StringBuilder, with amazing capacity calculation and estimation for the size of string builder, then it won't be an hack ? common, this is simple scenario with simple answer. I could give him in addition a Regex solution, Itrerative solution and couple more, but a simple question in this case with apparent simple solution, deserve simple solution.

Comment: A logical solution would be what @juharr has suggested because anyone reading the code would know, right away, it is replacing multiple commas with one comma and removing the leading comma. Self documenting code. [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2VSYAR). You can either take my comment as a friendly suggestion or an attack, but it's just a friendly suggestion.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, I'm taking it strictly as friendly suggestion, sorry if i was a bit aggressive. I wanted to give the regex solution as well and started to write it, but i've seen juharr beat me to it, so i gave up on putting it as well. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

```
text = ",,,,,9,33380,32785,14,,,,,50,,,,,,3,,,,600";
while (text.Contains(",,"))
{
    text = text.Replace(",,", ",");
}
if (text.Substring(0, 1) == ",") {
    int textLength = text.Length;
    text = text.Substring(1, textLength - 1);
}
```

hope it can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

@juharr's answer looks great, but if performance is a problem them it may be better to trim before replace and alter two or more commas to one. Thus giving:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(inpyut.Trim(','), ",,+", ",");
```

Comment: Do you know how I can then split the string into multiple strings? The delimited would be the comma. I'm trying this at the moment but it's not working. I can get the first value but not the second, third, fourth, etc... `var parts = result.Split(',');
                    var a = parts.First();
                    var b = parts.Skip(1).First();`

Comment: Try code like (untested) `foreach(var ss in result.Split(',')){Console.WriteLine($"<{ss}>");}` to see exactly what is in results. Your questions in comments do not give enough details to see why you get unexpected results.

Comment: Each line has 7 strings, separated by comma. So I try to make 7 strings out of it. So string a = the first value. string b = the second value. Each one is separated by the comma. Your foreach loop prints each word on a row, but how do I add those variables to strings named "a, b, c, d, e, f, g"?

Comment: So here is an example. After I run your code I get the string in a variable called "result", now I want to split it into smaller strings, like this: `string result = "100,33400,32780,13,50,2,600";

string a = "100";
string b = "33400";
string c = "32780";`

Comment: @MJ it appears you are attempting to ask a new question in the comments section that has nothing to do with the original question. If you have further questions please create a new question and be specific about your requirements.