# Delete a specific repeated character in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, slug

I've seen the following question [Regex to remove a specific repeated character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111967/regex-to-remove-a-specific-repeated-character) which is extremely similar to mine (if not exact) but it's implemented in C# and using that language's string methods.

I am wondering if someone could come up with a `javascript` implementation of it?

Example if you have

```
what---is-your-name- => what-is-your-name

---what-is----your-name-- => what-is-your-name
```

So how to remove the recurrence of a specific character, in this case `-` and replace it with just one `-` in javascript?

Comment: `Regex.Replace(inputString, "-+", "")` becomes `inputString.replace(/-+/g, "")`. `Trim` becomes `trim`. The `var`s work as they are.

Answer (score 7):

In one shot:

```
str.replace(/^-+|-+(?=-|$)/g, '')
```

explanations:

`(?=..)` is a lookahead assertion and means *followed by*. It is only a check and is not a part of the match result.

about `-+(?=-|$)`:

Since quantifiers are greedy by default `-+` matches all `-` in a part of the string, then the lookahead is tested: two possible situations

I. The part is in the middle of the string: `hello-----world`

since there is only a `w` after the lookahead fails and the regex engine go one character back. Now `-+` matches only four `-` that is followed by a `-`, the lookahead success. Since it is not  a part of the match, the last `-` is not removed by the replace function.

II. The part is at the end  of the string: `world-----`

`-+` matches all `-` until the end of the string and the second part of the lookahead assertion success. All `-` are removed by the replace function.

Note that `(?=-|$)` *(followed by a dash or the end of the string)* can also be written `(?![^-])` *(not followed by any character that is not a dash)* to avoid the alternation. It's the same but expressed in a negative way.

Comment: can you please tell how that positive lookahead works ?

Comment: @aelor: I have added a description.

Answer (score 3):

something like this

```
var str = "---what---is-your----name-----";
var res1 = str.replace(/^-+/,'');
console.log(res1);
var res2 = res1.replace(/-+$/,'');
console.log(res2);
var res3 = res2.replace(/-+/g,'-');
console.log(res3);
```

or you can simply put all the conditions into one for a one liner

```
str.replace(/^-+|-+$|-+/g,'-');
```

Comment: I split the lines to make it more clear to understand how it is happening

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
 var newValue = value.replace(/-+/g, '-');
```

Your example provided contradicts your description of the problem, since it looks like you want to remove all hyphens at the beginning and end. If so, this will do it:

```
 var newValue = value.replace(/^-+|-+$/g, '').replace(/-+/g, '-');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regexp

```
.replace(/\-+/g,'-').replace(/^-|-$/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation answer which only uses a single regular expression and one call to [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace); other answers still apply.

```
s = s.replace(/^-*|-*$|(-)-*/g, "$1");
```

So:

```
s = "---what-is----your-name--";
s = s.replace(/^-*|-*$|(-)-*/g, "$1");
// s == what-is-your-name
```

Explanation:

```
^-*    // match any number of dashes at the start
-*$    // match any number of dashes at the end
(-)-*  // match one or more dashes, capturing one dash in 1st group

/g     // match globally/repeatedly

"$1"   // replace with 1st group value;
       // so it will replace with "-" or "" (for undefined capture)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"what---is-your-name-".replace(/\-+/g, '-');
```